# Episerver Custom render blocks inside content area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, episerver

I created content area for jquery tabs.With block that contains TAB name and Tab content. The sturcture is like below

```html
<div id="tabs">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
        <li class="active" role="presentation">
            <a aria-controls="home" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">INTRODUCTION</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a aria-controls="profile" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">OUR HOLIDAYS TO ITALY</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a aria-controls="messages" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">ABOUT ITALIAN EXPRESSION</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a aria-controls="settings" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">ITALY HOLIDAY HIGHLIGHTS</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content tabgrey">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active country_content" id="home" role="tabpanel">test</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade country_content" id="profile" role="tabpanel">test</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade country_content" id="messages" role="tabpanel">test</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade country_content" id="settings" role="tabpanel">asdsadsad</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

If I try to render this structure through view of a block. I can't emulate it. 
Since I have to put all `li`'s inside one `ul` and all `div`s inside `tab-content`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to not render this with @Html.PropertyFor(), not with that markup anyway. Because you would end up with a lot of display templates and helper methods. Create a view model instead where everything is already put together nicely. Then loop through your view model twice, one time for the unordered list and then for every tab pane.

Comment: Can you write me a sample code so I can see what you mean, and so that I can accept your answer if it works.